# Image doesnt display with more than 4 item in flatlist in react native

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-flatlist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGyfi.png)Flatlist in react native, doesn't display more than 4 item.Remaining grid remains blank.Anyone please help me solving this issue.

Comment: please add the specific code

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Comment: Please find attached image of code snippet for your reference